# Field 'id' expected a number but got ''

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to display all the posts by a particular user in their profile page.. So if someone visits my profile page, they can see all of my posts and so on.

`all_post_by_user = Log.objects.filter(author=username)`

I am getting the post by a particular username.. author is defined in `models.py`

`username` is passed as an argument to the view..

I am getting the error [image]

views.py:

```
@verified_email_required
@login_required
def profile(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            message = messages.success(request, f'Your profile has been updated')
            return redirect('profile', username=username)

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    try:
        profile = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        message = messages.warning(request,f'Profile not found for {username}')

        return redirect('home')
        profile = ''

    print('profile name: ',profile.username)

    all_post_by_user = Log.objects.filter(author=username)
    print(all_post_by_user)
    context = {
        'u_form' : u_form,
        'p_form' : p_form,
        'profile' : profile, 
        'all_post_by_user' : all_post_by_user
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

It works if I changed it to     `all_post_by_user = Log.objects.filter(author=request.user)`

models.py:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=500)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images', blank=True)
```

Comment: The issue is likely that you're attempting to fetch records by their primary key but passing the username string in instead. Can you edit your question to leave out the template code but include your view function / class?

Comment: I have done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter with:

```
all_post_by_user = Log.objects.filter(author__username=username)
```

since we look for `Log` objects where the *`username`* of the `author` is the same as the given `username`.

Comment: Could you please answer this question?
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68004184/django-not-able-to-add-solution-to-a-particular-question-using-cbv/68004257)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your queryset is you're trying to query against a related model's primary key but passing the author's name instead of their ID.

When you use `author=<value>` , under the hood Django is going to take this as `author_id=<value>`. If you want to filter the queryset using a field *on* the Author model, you need to use `__` like so:

```
all_post_by_user = Log.objects.filter(author__name=username)
```

Now, when Django compiles the query you'll be filtering against the author's name rather than against the primary key.

Comment: `Related Field got invalid lookup: name`
I am getting this error when I change it

Comment: Well yes... you need to change `name` to whatever field you're trying to perform the lookup on. The above was an example as I don't know what fields your `Author` model has.

Comment: Author is a field in Log model   `author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)`

Comment: @Synctactic Fructose, Did u find any solution to this?

Comment: The solution is as provided above. All you need to do is use the related field you are trying to lookup on @Anirudh , I used `name` as an example. Replace `name` with whatever field corresponds to the username on your `User` model

Comment: Thanks @Syntactic Fructose
User model has the default fields so `author__username` worked